# Understanding UnboundLocalError in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am newbie to Python. While learning I came across below code snippets in that I am unable to understand behaviour of the code.
Here is first case

```
#Case 1
x=1
def func():
    x=5
    print(x)

func()
5
```

Here is second case

```
#Case 2  
x=1
def func():
    print(x) #First print statement
    x=5
    print(x) #Second print statement

func()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

The two cases are same except the second has one additional print statement. Why the first print statement of second snippet making the Python to throw an exception?

Comment: I thought the first print statement in second case will print value of global variable x i.e 1 and the second will print value of local x i.e 5. BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: Thanks Simeon! Now I understood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` outside the function is there but `x` is also defined in both functions as a local variable and you must define it before using it. It doesn't mean that Python will use the `x` from outside the function first and then allow you to redefine `x` as a local variable and then use the local variable `x` in the rest of the function.

So the difference is really between:

```
def func():
    x=5
    print(x)

def func():
    print(x) #First print statement
    x=5
    print(x) #Second print statement
```

In both functions `x` is a local variable but in the second function you're trying to use it before it's being defined in that function. Hence the error.